# Ошибка Undefined symbol "count"

Tags: borland, c++

Использую версию Borland 3.1. Мне нужно, чтобы это заработало:

```
#include <iostream.h>

void main(void)
{ 
    count << "Учимся программировать на языке C++!"; 
}
```

В компиляторе выдает ошибку

> Undefined symbol "count"

В чем проблема и как решить её?

Comment: \*facepalm\*

Comment: counnt?
std::cout <<" ";

Answer (score 3):

```
 cout <<  возможно? =)
```

Comment: всеравно есть ошибка и еше появиось после этого statement missing ;

Comment: statement missing ; означает что отсутствует точка с запятой:)

Answer (score 3):

```
//потому, что нужно писать

    cout << "wtf???";

//тем более, что надо указывать namespace либо в начале программы после #include<>  
    using namespace std;  
    //либо  
    std::cout << "";
```

Comment: По-моему у него древний компилятор. У него `#include <iostream`*.h*`>`. Этот заголовок появился ещё до выхода стандарта C++98, и тогда ещё не было никаких пространств имён. `#include <iostream>` появился уже после выхода этого стандарта, а в новых компиляторах старый файл убрали.

Comment: возможно так. раз уж у него iostream.h(у меня например iostream.h уже нет вообще, а в свете скорого выхода C++0x можно вообще забыть про iostream.h)  
но все равно о пространствах имен узнать полезно.